# How to convert File CreationTime into String in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, file-properties

All I found online were ways to write the *current* date into a string using `get-date.toString()`

What I want to do is read the `CreationDate` and Time from a File and convert that into a String for a directory name.

It would suffice if i could save the different parts of `CreationTime` into separate Variables.

E.g.: `$Year`, `$Month`, `$Day`, `$Hour` etc.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx .

i.e.

```
(gi C:\temp\trim.csv).CreationTime.ToString('ddd MM dd yyyy')
```

will give you a string "Wed 05 27 2015"

UPD:
or if you want to use string as a directory name just delete the spaces.

```
(gi C:\temp\trim.csv).CreationTime.ToString('dddMMddyyyy')
```

and get "Wed05272015"

Comment: I belive he wanted use file creation date as directory name, so there is no need to break out the properties, i've updated my answer.

Comment: You are right. I misread the original requirement and fixated on the compromise.

Comment: This answer works, but I would have used the format string 'yyyy-MM-dd', and I would have saved the result in some variable like $dirname.

Comment: `$dirname = (gi c:\temp\file.txt).CreationTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: This is what i was looking for.

Turns out all i was mising were the single quotes in the toString statement.

Thank you all for the swift replies

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = get-item c:\myfile.txt

$year = $file.creationtime.year
$month = $file.creationtime.month
$day = $file.creationtime.day
$hour = $file.creationtime.hour
```

and so on...

use  `$file.CreationTime | fl *` for a list of available properties

Comment: Yep. No need to create the variables. The properties already exist.

Comment: This answer is correct, if you just skip the (unnecessary) step of setting the variables $year, $month, $day, and use the members of CreationTime instead.